# Bootstrap clearfix mixin doesn't help in my case (to simplify HTML)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is some HTML using Bootstrap:

Code block **#1**

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <div class="clearfix" style="border:1px solid blue;">
    <h3>block#1 and block#2 should look the same way
    </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to remove `<div class="clearfix">` (and probably use .clearfix() mixin) to simplify HTML like this:

Code block **#2**

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
    <h3>block#1 and block#2 should look the same way
    </h3>
</div>
```

However, I'm unable to reach the same look even with using .clearfix().

Any suggestions how to make the **block #2** to look on the page as **block #1** with bootstrap mixins?

P.S. Of course the inline border styles are used to see paddings and placed here temporary.

I've tried this but it doesn't help:

```
<div style="border:1px solid red;">
  <h3 style="border:1px solid green;">block#1 and block#2 should look the same way
  </h3>
</div>
```

With this **CSS applied**:

```
h3 {
  .clearfix();
}
```

**unfortunately it looks not as #block1.**

[JSFiddle is here](https://jsfiddle.net/zdex771m/)

Comment: Are you using LESS/SCSS? Maybe good to add..

Comment: Seems like I've found the solution  - the clearfix mixin should be applied to the first, the very outer div block - to the parent, not to its own element (in our case h3).